# I want to run my automation unli times but sometimes it errors due to long loading

Tags: error-handling, robotframework

Im using robot framework on visual studio code, If it fails on any part of the automation I want it to rerun the whole test case automatically

I am new to coding/programming and chat gpt doesnt really help on this one. so please help hehe

Comment: Maybe you should also read the documentation https://docs.robotframework.org/docs/flaky_tests